URL parameters including a dash separated with a dash
Best approach to use dashed slugs separated by a dash:
get ':foo-:bar', to: 'foo#bar' 

foo could be my-value and bar could be other-value
My url is then my-value-other-value
What is the best approach to do this except changing the param separator to something else?
I do know all value for foo and all values for bar as these are stored in corresponding models. I'm afraid using this method will be poor in performances.

I don't see a problem with what you have. I suppose you are worried about using regex to evaluate the slug parameters? The performance hit will be very very small.

yes, to pretty much add on my route get '/:foo-:bar, to: '..', foo: /#{Foo.pluck(:slug).join('|')}/, bar: /#{Bar.pluck(:slug).join('|')}/

@LesNightingill doesn't Rails use a Regex to parse the request path no matter what? I can't see how this is acutally different than any other kind of route.

@max yeah probably, I never really thought about it.

@LesNightingill Because if my route is :foo-:bar and the value of foo is a-b and bar is c-d then my route is a-b-c-d and the regex won't work.

Because you know all the possible values for the two slug components, you can separate them by regex, even though they're dash-separated and may also contain a dash. The following regex will pull the slug values you're looking for:
my_value = ["big-deal","hoi-polloi","nodash"]
other_value = ["east-coast","chumbawumba","abba-zabba"]
regex = /^(#{my_value.join("|")})?-(#{other_value.join("|")})?/

test_strings = ["big-deal-wtf", "nodash-chumbawumba","nodash-abba-zabba","hoi-polloi-east-coast"]

test_strings.each {|string| match = string.match(regex); puts [match && match[1],match && match[2]].inspect}

the resulting matches are:
["big-deal", nil]
["nodash", "chumbawumba"]
["nodash", "abba-zabba"]
["hoi-polloi", "east-coast"]

does it meet your needs?
